# Centos 8 - VirtualBox 6.0 Install - kernel module issues

Tags: centos, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I recently installed a fresh copy of Centos 8 and am attempting to install VirtualBox-6.0 and ran into the following:

```
WARNING: The `vboxdrv` kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

         sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

I read online someone else who had the issue and ran the next command:

```shell
sudo /sbin/rcvbodrv setup
```

and got the following...

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.

This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules. Please
install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution. Please
install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system. The distribution
packages containing the headers are probably:
     kernel-devel kernel-devel-4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64
```

That being provided I downloaded the `gcc` `make` `perl`, the `kernel-devel` etc...

After that I re-ran the previous `/sbin` command and got the following:

```
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.
```

and in the log I see this...

```shellsession
$ cat /var/log/vbox-setup.log
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j8 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
Makefile:958: *** "Cannot generate ORC metadata for CONFIG_UNWINDER_ORC=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel".
Stop.
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:111: vboxdrv] Error 2
```

Now I'm at a loss as I'm not finding any leads anywhere...

**Update:9/30/2019**
@jsbillings noted the obvious to install the package `elfutils-libelf-devel`. It was a late night and totally missed reading that tid bit. I installed the following and rebuilt the kernel modules using:

```shell
sudo /sbin/rcvbodrv setup
```

Then I re-ran the VirtualBox command in the terminal and it worked like a charm!

Comment: You bolded a part of the text, did you install the packages it suggested?

Comment: The package is ‘elfutils-libelf-devel’ on C8

Comment: wow, yeah it was a late night... I ended up installing the **elfutils-libelf-devel** a moment ago.

I ended up running the VirtualBox command to have it error out; then I remembered to go back and run the **sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup** command to build the kernel modules. 

Once it build the modules I re-ran the VirtualBox command and it worked like a charm.

Thank you so much jsbillings!

Comment: +1  installed  elfutils-libelf-devel and run the sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup fixed the issue. thanks much.